# Prioitizing a Scrum Backlog

Tags: scrum, backlog

Our software company receives literally hundreds of support requests per day and there's a whole team working on our inbox. How can we gain effective metrics that map directly to our Scrum backlogs?

If we're too specific, the team has too constantly beware of changing  metrics, if we're too general, the PO has to sort through too many emails to get reliable priority.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use only emails? Or do you use a bug/issue tracking system sort of like Atlassian Jira? Just wondering cause you can have emails feed Jira and then you can assign points and weights and different things to issues, link them to burn down charts and what not through the Greenhopper plugin. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "support requests"?

Assuming 3 broad buckets:

1. "How do I do x?" type questions
2. "This isn't working right" (i.e. a defect)
3. "It would be really helpful if it did y." enhancement requests

Within each of the categories (you may have more or less than 3, but 3 is a good number to work with), assign some tags that categorize the request.  I like to organize the categories as labels for vertical columns, and put a 'flag' for each request in the column.  This give a quick and dirty vertical bar chart, and I almost guarantee you'll see a Pareto ratio emerge, wherein 20% of the 'tags' result in 80% of the requests.  Now your PO can prioritize among/across the 20% of each of the 3 broad buckets, knowing that they are the high-value ones.

You can keep this as a running exercise.